# Quicksight, How to Show Totals in specific format

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am new to Quicksight and really appreciate some help.
I have an analysis that looks like this and the spice dataset is from a query . (I uploaded an image but can't be seen unfortunately, as this is a question mostly about formatting.)

| Package Group | Capacity Value | Capacity Used | Capacity Left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Great yield | 200 | 10 | 140 |
| Good Yield | 180 | 30 | 120 |
| Volume | 150 | 20 | 90 |

Capacity Left is calculated as: Capacity Value - Sum(Capacity Used)
e.g. (200-(10+30+20)) = 140

I didn't know exactly how to accomplish that through Quicksight, so is coming from the query.

My main issue is to show the **Totals**.
It needs to be shown like this. (uploaded the image but can't be seen)

| Package Group | Capacity Value | Capacity Used | Capacity Left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Great yield | 200 | 10 | 140 |
| Good Yield | 180 | 30 | 120 |
| Volume | 150 | 20 | 90 |

```
           Total Capacity:                     200
           ---------------------------------------
           Total Used Capacity:                60
           ---------------------------------------
           Total Remaining Capacity            140
           ---------------------------------------
```

(that goes aligned to the right)

So, I can not add the normal Total because it would go under each column, and what I need is in a row based, like I am trying to show here, Also Totals are calculated like this:

Total Capacity is :        max(Capacity Value)

Total Capacity Used is :   the normal Sum(Capacity Used)

Total Capacity Left is:    Total Capacity - Total Capacity Used

Please any help would be greatly appreciated. If i need to provide any more information, please let me know.

Thanks,
Tatiana.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ie6E.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the Total Capacity, Total Capacity Used and Total Capacity Left using your definitions in a separate Pivot table... and then change the Column to display as Row from the field well:
[image: Change Columns to Row]

You can further refine it by switching to free-form to have better control on the placement of the visuals to get it as close as possible to how you would like it to look.
[image: Free form]

Comment: Thank you! @darcoli, I am going to try that. So it can not be something in the same visual?, I need to add another visual (table) and define only the Totals?.

Comment: Thank you very much @darcoli,  it worked!.  Added another visual for the Totals (a table), changed it to Rows, and the magic worked with the 'Free Form' to make it look as needed.